# Why the velocity vector is perpendicular to the position vector in a circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, velocity

I know by definition it should be perpendicular I just don't get why

Comment: The statement is false in general since position (even if the motion is on a circle) is relative. The statement only true if the origin of the coordinates is in the center of the circle. In that case the position vector has a constant length, you can prove I hope that the derivative of any vector-valued function (of time), the length of it(s images) is constant, is perpendicular to it at every point

Comment: 'By definition' the position vector connect the center of rotation with the particle. That way the $\vec{r}$ is always perpendicular to the $\vec{v}$.

Comment: $$
\| \vec r(t)\|:= \sqrt{ \vec r(t)\cdot\vec r(t)} = const \implies \dot{\vec r} (t) \cdot \vec r(t) = 0
$$

Comment: yes but why ? (consider that the origin of the coordinates in the center of the circle yes) why the vector is tangent to the circle in that particle ?

Comment: Well, the velocity is defined as $\dot{\vec r} (t)$ which is the definition of *a* tangent vector to the curve traced out by $\vec r (t)$

Comment: pardon me, I am a slow learner you said defined my mind can't understand the logic behind that for instance why isn't in the same direction or any other direction but perpendicular

Comment: If it wasn't perpendicular the object would go off in some direction *not* on the circle.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a particle undergoing circular motion around an origin $O$ in a plane (2D). By the definition of circular motion, the position vector relative to $O$) is

$$
\vec{r} = r \cos (\omega t) \hat{x} + r \sin (\omega t) \hat{y} ,
$$

where $\omega$ is the angular velocity (the angle $\theta = \omega t$, analogous to $x = vt$ for rectilinear motion).

To get the velocity vector, we of course just differentiate $\vec{r}$ with respect to $t$, giving

$$
\dot{\vec{r}} = - r \omega \sin (\omega t) \hat{x} + r \omega \cos (\omega t) \hat{y} .
$$

It is then trivial to check that $\vec{r} \cdot \dot{\vec{r}}$ (the dot product) is always zero, hence $\vec{r}$ and $\dot{\vec{r}}$ are perpendicular. Indeed, the velocity is always tangential to the perimeter of the circle (i.e., the path of the particle), as you would expect.

Pictorially, this may help.

[image]

$\vec{\Omega}$ here is the vector version of $\omega$; it has magnitude $\omega$, directed "out of the page", i.e., $\vec{\Omega} := \omega \vec{z}$. (And of course we have $\vec{v} := \dot{\vec{r}}$.)

You should be able to check yourself using the above equations that $\dot{\vec{r}} = \vec{\Omega} \times \vec{r}$, just like in the diagram, by computing the cross product directly. This is another intuitive way to see how the position and velocity vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: @caplok123 Great. Do please upvote and/or accept, unless you have a further question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

***Theorem***: Let $I \subset \mathbb R$ and $v:I \to \mathbb R^n$ be smooth (regular) curve, i.e. $\|\frac{d}{dt}v(t)\| \neq 0$ for any $t \in I$. Assume further that $v$ is such that $\|v(t)\|^2 = const$ over $I$. Then $\langle \frac{d}{dt}v(t),v(t) \rangle = 0$.

***Proof***
$$
\|v(t)\|^2 =  const \implies 0 = \frac{d}{dt}\|v(t)\|^2 = 0 \iff \langle \frac{d}{dt}v(t),v(t) \rangle = 0
$$
where $\|v(t)\|^2 = \langle v(t),v(t) \rangle$.

Comment: While this is nice from a certain perspective, it is not quite what the OP wants, since what it shows is that velocity and acceleration are perpendicular with essentially the assumption of conservation of kinetic energy of a fixed-mass particle.

Comment: Interpret $v$ as $\vec r$. There is no mention of accelerartion here. You are deceived by the letter $v$ as if it indicates velocity, got it ?

Comment: Ah, fair enough then. I had my physics hat on with regards to notation. Just to be perfectly explicit to the OP: this is another valid derivation, where the assumption of constant $||v||^2$ is just equivalent to the curve being a circle (constant radius).

Comment: Correct, and sorry for the rude comment.

Comment: No worries... suspected it was just a little frustration. No harm done.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for the Frenet-Serret frame* : $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=\frac{ds}{dt} \frac{d\vec{r}}{ds}=v(\frac{dx}{ds}\vec{i}+\frac{dy}{ds}\vec{j})=v[\cos(\theta)\vec{i}+\sin(\theta)\vec{j}]=v\vec{T} $

$(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)) \;$ the coordinates of the unit vector tengent to the plane curve.

In another manner :

$\vec{r}=r\cos(\alpha)\vec{i}+r\sin(\alpha)\vec{j}=r[\cos(\alpha)\vec{i}+\sin(\alpha)\vec{j}]=r\vec{e}_{r}$

with $\; r=cst\;, \alpha =\omega t$

$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=\frac{dr}{dt}\vec{e}_{r}+r\frac{d\vec{e}_{r}}{dt}=0+r\frac{d\vec{e}_{r}}{dt} \;\;\;$ (1)

$\frac{d\vec{e}_{r}}{d\alpha}=-\sin(\alpha)\vec{i}+\cos(\alpha)\vec{j}=\vec{e}_{\alpha}$

we can see that $\;\vec{e}_{r}.\vec{e}_{\alpha}=0$

we replace in (1)

$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=r\frac{d\vec{e}_{r}}{dt}=r\frac{d\vec{e}_{r}}{d\alpha}\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=r\omega \vec{e}_{\alpha}=v\vec{e}_{\alpha}$

with $\;\;\vec{e}_{r}\perp \vec{e}_{\alpha} $

(*) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector

Answer (score 0):

The centripetal vector is directed inwards (towards centre of the circular path), while velocity vector is tangential to the particle in motion and, hence, makes an angle to 90$^\circ$. So basically, centripetal acceleration and velocity vector are at an angle of 90$^\circ$.

Comment: No need to thank me. Yo, based?